# Unable to Map Complex Entity Framework Core using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm struggling to figure out how to correctly map an EF core object with inheritance to a DTO using AutoMapper.  The correct result I'm looking for is a DTO that has one Training AND ALL the Employees that are registered for it:

Here are the three classes:

```
public class Training
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string Host { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public ICollection<EmployeeTraining> EmployeeTrainings { get; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EmployeeTraining> EmployeeTrainings { get; }
}

public class EmployeeTraining    
{
    public Guid EmployeeId {get; set;}
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public Guid TrainingId { get; set; }
    public Training Training{ get; set; }
}

public class TrainingDTO
{
     public string Host { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public ICollection<EmployeeTraining> EmployeeTrainings { get; }
}
```

> AutoMapper Profile:

```
public class TrainingProfile: Profile
{
    public TrainingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Training, TrainingDto>()
            .ForMember(entity => entity.EmployeeTrainings, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model));
        CreateMap<TrainingDto, Training>();
    }
}
```

> The code compiles, but when run I get:

```
[2021-05-03T21:21:49.201Z] Exception: Error mapping types.
[2021-05-03T21:21:49.203Z] Mapping types:
[2021-05-03T21:21:49.204Z] Training -> TrainingDto
[2021-05-03T21:21:49.208Z] AzITSSMaster.API.Entities.Training -> AzITSSMaster.API.Models.TrainingDto
[2021-05-03T21:21:49.209Z] Type Map configuration:
[2021-05-03T21:21:49.209Z] Training -> TrainingDto
[2021-05-03T21:21:49.211Z] AzITSSMaster.API.Entities.Training -> AzITSSMaster.API.Models.TrainingDto
[2021-05-03T21:21:49.212Z] Destination Member:
[2021-05-03T21:21:49.212Z] EmployeeTrainings
```

> Test

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Guid trainingOneGuid = new Guid("5b1c2b4e48c7402a80c3cc796ad49c6b");
        Guid trainingTwoGuid = new Guid("d8663e5f74944f8187396e0de1bea7ee");
        Guid employeeOneGuid = new Guid("5b1c2b4d48c7402a80c3cc796ad49c6b");
        Guid employeeTwoGuid = new Guid("d8663e5e74944f8187396e0de1bea7ee");

        //Create In Memory Database
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ITSSAPIContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "ITSSMaster")
        .Options;

        using (var context = new ITSSAPIContext(options))
        {
            TrainingRepository trepo = new TrainingRepository(context);
            EmployeeRepository erepo = new EmployeeRepository(context);
            EmployeeTrainingRepository etrepo = new EmployeeTrainingRepository(context);

            // Create
            trepo.Create(new Training
            {
                Id = trainingOneGuid,
                Host = "ATS",
                Name = "ATS Test Training 1",
                StartDate = DateTime.Now,
                Facillitator = "Darth Maul",
                StipendAmount = 750,

            });

            trepo.Create(new Training
            {
                Id = trainingTwoGuid,
                Host = "CO",
                Name = "CO Test Training 1",
                StartDate = DateTime.Now,
                Facillitator = "Darth Vader",
                StipendAmount = 0
            });

            erepo.Create(new Employee
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("5b1c2b4d-48c7-402a-80c3-cc796ad49c6b"),
                OrgDefinedId = 000032615,
                Designation = String.Empty
            });

            erepo.Create(new Employee
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("d8663e5e-7494-4f81-8739-6e0de1bea7ee"),
                OrgDefinedId = 000012345,
                Designation = "Champion"
            });

            //Training: GetIncluding
            Training training1 = trepo.GetIncluding<Training>(
                trainingOneGuid,
                c => c.EmployeeTrainings);
            Assert.Equal("ATS Test Training 1", training1.Name);

            Training training2 = trepo.GetIncluding<Training>(
                trainingTwoGuid,
                c => c.EmployeeTrainings);
            Assert.Equal("CO Test Training 1", training2.Name);

            //Employee: GetIncluding
            Employee employee1 = erepo.GetIncluding<Employee>(
                employeeOneGuid,
                c => c.EmployeeTrainings);
            Assert.Equal(000032615, employee1.OrgDefinedId);

            Employee employee2 = erepo.GetIncluding<Employee>(
            employeeTwoGuid,
            c => c.EmployeeTrainings);
            Assert.Equal(000012345, employee2.OrgDefinedId);

            //EmployeeTraining:  Add
            etrepo.AddTrainingToEmployee(employee1, training1);
            etrepo.AddTrainingToEmployee(employee2, training1);
            Assert.Equal(2, training1.EmployeeTrainings.Count);

            etrepo.AddTrainingToEmployee(employee1, training2);
            Assert.Equal(1, training2.EmployeeTrainings.Count);

            Assert.Equal(2, employee1.EmployeeTrainings.Count);
            Assert.Equal(1, employee2.EmployeeTrainings.Count);

            //Automapper
            var config1 = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Training, TrainingDto>()
                    .ForMember(dst => dst.EmployeeTrainings, 
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.EmployeeTrainings));
            });

            //Using automapper
            var mapper1 = new Mapper(config1);
            var TrainingDto1 = mapper1.Map<TrainingDto>(training1);
            var TrainingDto2 = mapper1.Map<TrainingDto>(training2);
        }
    }
```

> Watch Window

[image: Watch Window]

Answer (score 0):

First, check that you've registered your profiles by calling the `IServiceCollection` extension method AddAutoMapper at application startup:

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

Then, slightly change your `EmployeeTrainings` assignment into this:

```
    CreateMap<Training, TrainingDto>()
        .ForMember(dst => dst.EmployeeTrainings, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.EmployeeTrainings));
```

Comment: The inheritance doesn't work as expected (The DTO's EmployeeTraining field is null) I've added my test code and the results (Watch Window above).  Thank you for looking at this - I've been trying to solve this for two days.

Comment: I don't see any connection between inheritance and your scenario. All of your classes inherit from _object_

Comment: Sorry - I jumble up the terminology sometimes.  What I'm trying to do is get all the employees who are part of the training object mapped to the training DTO so that those employees are returned along with the training when the training data is returned to the user.

Comment: I really think that it's a poor choice to keep having the EmployeeTraining class referenced by the DTO object. I would encourage you to create an EmployeeTrainingDto. Why? Because of navigation properties: Before mapping, EmployeeTraining.Training is referencing the Training object. What do you expect to happen with this reference after mapping?